# AndroidJavaProxy is not an interface

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use an Android phone's camera in Unity. I need to pass a `CameraDevice.StateCallback` to the [`CameraManager.openCamera`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#openCamera(java.lang.String,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) method, which I have constructed as such:

```
public class OpenCameraCallbackProxy : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public OpenCameraCallbackProxy() : base("android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice$StateCallback")
    {

    }

    public void onOpened(AndroidJavaObject cameraDevice)
    {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

When calling the openCamera method (`cameraManager` is an instance of `AndroidJavaObject`):

```
cameraManager.Call("openCamera", cameraId, new OpenCameraCallbackProxy(), null);
```

I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice$StateCallback is not an interface`.

I am also using a proprietary Java library elsewhere in my application which uses callbacks, and this method (using `AndroidJavaProxy`) works properly. I'm guessing that there must be a check in `openCamera` to throw if not `callback.getClass().isInterface()` or something like that. Is there any way I could get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AndroidJavaProxy's constructor requires the fully qualified name string of the *interface to be implemented* for the callback. Presumably this is because the object passed back to you is a runtime constructed class, so its signature is not available at compile time, but that the code that constructs the runtime object *can* implement a given interface (how? I have no idea, other than it would use [ASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM), but that's like saying "I don't know how they made that dresser, but a saw was probably involved").

However, [CameraDevice.StateCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback.html) is not an interface, it is an abstract class.

The Unity example for using the [AndroidJavaProxy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaProxy.html) uses a [DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html) callback interface, which we can see is actually an interface.

I am not sure what you should be doing instead (possibly subclassing `CameraDevice.StateCallback`? That's what [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529057/android-camera2-api-opencamera-error) did) as I've never tried to do this, but that's why you're getting the error your getting.